# image url from uploaded wordpress not showing to my website

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I can`t use images uploaded from a worpress site to my custom site.

In my site i use an import from feed where image name is an URL.

The url with image is opening fine in new tab (if i inspect the source and open url)...but in my site the image is not showing.

In console also get:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

In my source code the image url is there:

```
<img class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 400px;" src="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/image_name.png" alt="image_name">
```

I am having this problem ONLY with this wordpress site with image urls, from other sites the image urls are working fine.

Could be a wordpress restriction or something like that?

Comment: Plugin may cause of it . So deactivate plugin one by one and check.

Comment: i don't have access to the worpress site, it`s not mine. I use that website only for resources (images) :)

Comment: can you share frontend link of it ?

Comment: Here is an image from their website: https://polisanopharmaceuticals.ro/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/big_vitamina-c-1000-mg-eliberare-prelungita.png

Comment: here every image is displaying properly can you share the site link where image is not displaying. In this site every image displaying properly.

Comment: I know...but in my code is not showing the image only alt. My website is on localhost (can't share a link) and  the problem is only with this website. Other external image url are working fine (from other westite). Could be a plugin issue on their wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin server checks the referer header of image requests - maybe to prevent embedding images on unknown websites.

There are ways to prevent sending referer headers like:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

Comment: This host checks for a given referer. If it's set to an unknown domain (like localhost) it answers with a 404 page and not the image. The workaround here is to not send any referer to the host, so it cannot check the domain of the website and answers with the correct image.

Comment: if the host cannot check the domain website...that means there is a plugin (or something like a white list) which allows some domains to use the resources images....

Comment: There are some ways to do this. [Here](http://webcraft.tools/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-in-wordpress/) is a tutorial how to do this.